# Trying to get response using curl exec

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get a response.

Using `curl_exec` works fine, but the problem is that it gets a response with different IP.

I want to get response from client or user IP, rather than server IP.

```
$URL = "https://drive.google.com/get_video_info?docid=".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 2);
$response_data = urldecode(urldecode(curl_exec($curl)));
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/get_video_info?docid=0B5iKi5djQFdXYTFoWmNsemNqX1U 
 im trying to get google video info and in video info url contain with ip for which its generated 
im writing script which get this info works fine but problem is when the url generated using curl ip address is different not mine

Comment: I would recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to increase your chances of getting help. Your question, in its current form, is rather hard to understand what you are asking.

Comment: you can see in images may b help to describe better
http://imgur.com/a/Sx9zf

Comment: It is due to redirections maybe?

Comment: Updated grammar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `curl` runs on the server and not in the client. Any HTTP command issued by curl will use the server IP as the requester.

- Depending on the service you are invoking, probably you can use the `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header used in the Internet Proxies.

  ```
  $URL = "https://drive.google.com/get_video_info?docid=".$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"];
  $curl = curl_init();

  // set the command as requested by the client IP
  curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Forwarded-For: '. $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));      

  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 2);
  $response_data = urldecode(urldecode(curl_exec($curl)));
  ```

The service you are invoking may use the header to determine the ip of the originator. Using the `X-Forwarded-For` will not work with all the services and server-side frameworks.

- If you want to make a request from the client, probably you need to use javascript (e.g. by using `XMLHttpRequest` or some functions in JQuery or Angular) to make the request.

You may check:

- more on obtaining the client IP in PHP, for instance when the client is behind a proxy or a `X-Forwarded-For`: [Get the client IP address using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15699101/get-the-client-ip-address-using-php)
- more about using `X-Forwarded-For` with curl:  [How can I spoof the sender IP address using curl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188584/how-can-i-spoof-the-sender-ip-address-using-curl)

Comment: thankyou for your answer exactly you understand my problem but unfortunately this solution not work for me :(

Comment: There are other forwarding headers in addition to `X-Forwarded-For`-
 You may check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13111080/what-is-a-full-specification-of-x-forwarded-proto-http-header -- If the API you are using does not recognize that (or other) forwarding headers, you must use javascript to create a connection from the browser itself.

Answer (score 0):

get the client to install curl on its own computer, and run the code there, or get the client to install a proxy on its computer, then proxy your connection through the client's with CURLOPT_PROXY    & co.